# Create a register of persons with references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, glossaries

To
[Create a register of persons with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79342/create-a-register-of-persons-with-biblatex) seems to be much more complicate than I expected.

How can I create nice a register of persons semiautomatic with `\ref`?

I have 20 persons that should be mentioned in a document. 
The grouping and sorting is complicate to implement in LaTeX, but I could do that very easy by hand and LaTeX could manage links and backlinks for me.

At the moment I use a solution like [How do I include all authors of cited works in an index of persons?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4082/how-do-i-include-all-authors-of-cited-works-in-an-index-of-persons). It works but it can not handle the manual grouping and sorting.

The final document with hyperlinks and backlinks should look like

```
The sample was prepared by \person[Mr.]{Miller}.
```

> ```
> Register of Persons
> ===================
> Prof. Dr. M. Miller, University of M (p. 4, 12)
> Dr. A. Foobar, University of M (p. 5)
>
> B. Foo, University of Z (p. 1)
> ```

Comment: Have a look at  the `nameauth` package.

Comment: `nameauth` is a good way to go (though I've only looked at the package, never used it).  Another way to do it is with an index: as long as you put all your frequently names in macros and provide a 'general' name macro for one-off uses, it would not be hard to 'group' (i.e., sort) as you please.  In the index approach, the `xparse` package will allow you to create pretty clever name+(conditional-)index macros pretty easily.  See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74536/8528) for a related question.

Comment: I could not find anything about hyperlinks nor an register in the manual of [nameauth](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nameauth).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this using the `glossaries` package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{datatool-base}% provides \DTLinitials
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

% Syntax: \newperson{label}{title}{forenames}{surname}{affiliation}
\newcommand*{\newperson}[5]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#1}%
  {%
     name={#2\space\DTLinitials{#3}\space#4},
     sort={#5},% sort on affiliation
     description={#5},% affiliation
     text={#2\ #4},% title \space surname
     user1={#2},% title
     user2={#3},% forenames
     user3={#4}% surname
  }%
}

\let\Ptitle\glsuseri
\let\Pforenames\glsuserii
\let\Psurname\glsuseriii

\newglossarystyle{person}%
{%
   \glossarystyle{list}%
   \glsnogroupskiptrue
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[]\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2},
       ##3 (p.~##5)}%
}%

\makeglossaries

\newperson{miller}{Prof.\ Dr.}{Marmaduke}{Miller}{University of M}
\newperson{foobar}{Dr.}{Aardvark}{Foobar}{University of M}
\newperson{foo}{Mr}{Bar}{Foo}{University of Z}

\begin{document}

The screwdriver was turned by \gls{miller}.
The hammer was whacked by \gls{foobar}.
\Gls{foo}['s] thumb throbbed.

\printglossary[title={Register of Persons},style=person]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can not see a  glossary. TeXLive2012 generated 1 page with: `The screwdriver was turned by Prof. Dr. Miller. The hammer was whacked
by Dr. Foobar. Mr Foo's thumb throbbed.` Thats all.

Comment: @JonasStein you need to run `makeglossaries` or `makeindex`. This is described in the `glossaries` manual and also in [an article on LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/55-latex-general/263-glossaries-nomenclature-lists-of-symbols-and-acronyms)

Comment: I had to edit `.latexmkrc` now it works http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/how-to-make-latexmk-use-makeglossaries

Comment: is it possible to print the section title instead of the pagenumer? see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83750/glossaries-using-name-of-subsections-instead-of-page-numbers)

Answer (score 3):

Alas, `nameauth` will not do the forward referencing. It will respect the index entry links back to the pages in question.

Here is a MWE of what `nameauth` does generally accomplish. What you get is a focus on auto-formatting of names. The package is meant (mostly) for printed matter. Thanks, however, for this post. It gives me an idea for expansion of features at some point.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nameauth}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\title{nameauth test}
\author{}
\date{}
\frenchspacing

\begin{nameauth}
  \<Miller & Prof. Dr. M. & Miller & >
  \<Foobar & Dr. A. & Foobar & >
  \<Foo & B. & Foo & >
\end{nameauth}

\TagName[Prof. Dr. M.]{Miller}{, University of M}
\TagName[Dr. A.]{Foobar}{, University of M}
\TagName[B.]{Foo}{, University of Z}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section 1}

The screwdriver was turned by \LMiller.
Do you call him \SMiller[Martin] or just \Miller?
I liked \LMiller[Mr.]'s lectures.
Not so much those of \LFoobar.
I thought \LFoobar[Mr.] was a little disjointed in his presentation.
I hear the new up-and-comer is \LFoo.
Do you know \Foo{} like I know \Foo?

\clearpage

\section{Section 2}

The screwdriver was turned by \LMiller.
Do you call him \SMiller[Martin] or just \Miller?
I liked \LMiller[Mr.]'s lectures.
Not so much those of \LFoobar.
I thought \LFoobar[Mr.] was a little disjointed in his presentation.
I hear the new up-and-comer is \LFoo.
Do you know \Foo{} like I know \Foo?

\clearpage

\printindex

\end{document}
```