Is there a way to retroactively add subsections inside sections?
Right now I'm trying to create a DnD campaign using LaTeX (TeXstudio) to write my story as a DM. My idea is to make a command that adds NPC's to the section at the end of the document as a subsection. I.e. I want to create a command that adds subsections to the section but that command should make subsections before said section have even been made. Is this even possible? And if it isn't then what are your ideas to implement NPC/Monsters/Events listing at the end of the document without explicitly writing them there (i.e. I write them where they are mentioned and then they are listed there automatically (with a \newcommand{\NPC} for example))?
Another of my ideas is to make a NPC database with a datatool package but I don't understand how to do this. If this can work then how to add a NPC to the database with columns like: Country, Title, Race? And how to show it like text and not table?
Answers are greatly appreciated
Edit: Dungeons and Dragons is a tabletop rpg game where there are players and Dungeon Master or Game Master. Right now I'm tring to write a story with a characters that will be used many times. So I want something like this:
\NPC{King Richard}{King, 4lvl, warrior} is a powerful warrior...

Turned into: King Richard is a powerful warrior
But at the end of the document there should be something like:
-NPCs:
    -King Richard. King, 4lvl, warrior

-Events:
    -Dungeon 1
    -Dungeon 2

I will try to use glossary as stated in first suggestion and if it won't work I will try endfloat. I deeply appreciate your efforts and time. Thank you! (I won't close this suggestion yet, maybe someone will come with an even better answer for someone with the same problem)

Sounds like a glossary or similar. See, e.g., package glossaries, package bib2gls, package arco ans similar.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. The example could either fake the wanted result and you use it to explain the wanted difference in usage or the other way round.

Welcome. // Please define or explain your abbreviations DnD, DM, NPC. Thank you

you would need to add an example to make your question clear enough to answer but possibly you just need, at various points in the document \AtEndDocument{\subsection{wibble} something about wibble} so a bunch of subsections appear at the end.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

One can manipulate the endfloat package to move enviorments (which may include subsections) to the end of a document.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452596/auto-order-appendices

Some possible approaches from previous questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82659/create-a-register-of-persons-with-references, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79342/create-a-register-of-persons-with-biblatex (same use case as the first question, different approach), https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62982/list-of-people-analog-to-bibliography

Here another one with acro: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354031/creating-an-index-of-persons-with-references?noredirect=1&lq=1

This one is interesting as well, without any packages: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267724/effective-way-to-anonymise-interviewee-identities-for-academic-research?noredirect=1&lq=1
